# Angular $http cache not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angular's http cache but the result is undefined. Cache returns an object but usersCache is undefined.

controller in main.js

```
app.controller('exploreController', function($scope, dataService, $cookies, $cacheFactory, $http) {
// dataService.explorePosts();

$scope.explore = function(){
    dataService.explorePosts();
    var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
    console.log(cache);
    var usersCache = cache.get('http://dstm.herokuapp.com/api/explore');
    console.log(usersCache);

};

$scope.explore();
});
```

service in data.js

```
angular.module('dsnApp')
.service('dataService', function($http, $cookies, $cacheFactory) {  
   this.explorePosts = function(){
    var id = $cookies.get("userId");
    $http.get('http://dstm.herokuapp.com/api/explore', {cache: true,
     params: {userId: id, page: 1},
   })
   .then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

Comment: controller('exploreController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory', function($scope, dataService, $cookies, $cacheFactory, $http) {

Comment: can you create a working **plnkr**?

Comment: $http is asynchronous.Nothing will be cached until the request completes and you are trying to access the cache synchronously

Answer (score 1):

@charlietfl is right.

> $http is asynchronous.Nothing will be cached until the request
>   completes and you are trying to access the cache synchronously.

To make this work as you expect:

First, make the `this.explorePosts` function return the `promise`, which `$http` service alredy returns.

```
   this.explorePosts = function(){
     var id = $cookies.get("userId");
     return $http.get('http://dstm.herokuapp.com/api/explore', {cache: true,
       params: {userId: id, page: 1},
     })
     .then(function successCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
     });
   };
```

Then use the cache in the promise's `then` callback.

```
$scope.explore = function() {
    dataService.explorePosts().then(function () {
        var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
        console.log(cache);
        var usersCache = cache.get('http://dstm.herokuapp.com/api/explore');
        console.log(usersCache);
    });
};
```

Comment: Actually don't really even need the cachefactory. If the `then()` in service was removed `then()` in controller would always see the response object but only one request would ever be made due to the cache config

Comment: This is right, but i think the OP just want to explore the cache for the educational purposes.

Comment: Right, was just mentioning it as OP may not be aware either